# Unexpected developer error, please try again later Google pay

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, braintree, google

[image]

Im facing this issue when I try to use google pay.

[image]

**Note: It's working in sandbox environment.**

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while calling from Android APK. Any update how you have resolved it? Or we have to write native android code for mobile?